# Word matching calculation

Tags: r

I want to put a weight when a list of word match an other list but i don t understand how to do it.
Here is an example :

```
require("stringr")

sample = c("You're awesome and I love you",
"I hate and hate and hate. So angry. Die!")
word.neg = c("hate","angry.")
word.neg.coef =c(-20,-4)


word.list = str_split(sample, '\\s+')

sapply(word.list,function(x) match(x,word.neg))



test <- lapply(word.list, function(x) sum(!is.na(match(x,neg.words))) )
test2 <-unlist(test)

data.frame(sample,test2)
```

As you can see the match return the position of the word  after i do a sum of true.

But what i want to do is to apply a weight that means each time it sees hate it apply -20 and each time it see angry. it apply -4 
so at the end i want something like this

```
data.frame(sample,score=c(0,-24))
```

In other words what is the best way to lookup a sentence with a list of words and apply a coefficient.
My other question is also to know if there is something to have to words instead of the position:

```
 sapply(word.list,function(x) match(x,word.neg))
```

This

[[2]]
    [1] NA  hate NA  hate NA NA NA  angry. NA

Instead of this :

```
[[2]]
[1] NA  1 NA  1 NA NA NA  2 NA
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 sapply(word.list,function(x) word.neg[match(x,word.neg)])
 #[[1]]
 #[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA

 #[[2]]
 #[1] NA       "hate"   NA       "hate"   NA       NA       NA       "angry."
 #[9] NA      

 sapply(word.list,function(x) (as.numeric((word.neg.coef[match(x,word.neg)]))))
 #[[1]]
 #[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA

 #[[2]]
 #[1]  NA -20  NA -20  NA  NA  NA  -4  NA

 sapply(word.list,function(x) sum(word.neg.coef[match(x,word.neg)], na.rm = T))
#[1]   0 -44
```

Comment: I like the way you build up to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite the answer but maybe is more what you want with less effort.  The `qdap` package offers the `polarity` function to do sentiment analysis.  You can also supply a custom dictionary with weights as you're doing via `sentiment_frame`:

```
library(qdap)
polarity(sample, id(sample))

##   sample total.sentences total.words ave.polarity sd.polarity stan.mean.polarity
## 1      1               1           6        0.816          NA                 NA
## 2      2               1           9       -1.667          NA                 NA
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler i am going to look at your package. In fact i wanted to know how to do it step by step to better understand R manipulation. But as i am learning sentiment analysis it's always good to know packages that can do it with less effort :)

Comment: @bimetcarentre Yes that's definitely important.  You may arrive at a different algorithm based on need for accuracy, philosophy of functional linguistics, and efficiency of the algorithm.